# django - deploy project to heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I have an django project (RESTful API written using Django Rest Framework) which uses the **Postgres** database.

I have a local **git repository** of the project and also I have it on my **github** account, and I want to deploy the porject to **heroku**.

In the official heroku tutorials, they don't show anything about how to prepare your app to deployment - (requirements file, settings file, Proc File, maybe more stuff that I don't know - which I saw in different tutorials that you need to do).

At the moment I only have the django app without any added file.

**My question is** - what do I need to do to prepare my app to deployment to **heroku**? as I said at the moment I have a local **git repository** and its also on **Github**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a file called Procfile (no extension) in your project root with the following inside:
`web: gunicorn APP_NAME.wsgi` (replace APP_NAME with your app's name).

2) Pip install `gunicorn` and `dj-database-url`

3) In your virtual env terminal, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in your project root (do this every time you `pip install` any new packages).

4) In your production settings file, add the following to make your database work on heroku:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

Note: This will cause errors in your local environment, so make sure you have a `prod.py` settings file as well (ask if you need an explanation).

5) Add heroku to your git settings via `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:HEROKU_APP_NAME.git` (replace HEROKU_APP_NAME with your Heroku app name).

6) Once you do `git add --all`, `git commit -m "SOME MESSAGE HERE"` and `git push`, you can do `git push heroku master`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! one question - i work in pyCharm, so I don't really know what is the virtual env terminal. is that where I run "python manage.py shell"? in the app directory

Comment: No worries, I work in PyCharm also... for starters, do you have a Virtual Environment set up? (shell is just a Django console)

Comment: Not really sure, I did pip install virtualenv.. that the only thing I did with virtualenv

Comment: and also need explanation about  "make sure you have a prod.py settings file as well"... thanks again

Comment: Alright, so these are both important concepts. I will try my best to add them to my answer, but for now if you follow what I wrote it should still work in production (just make sure to add step 4 at the END of your settings.py file).

Comment: Okay thanks. worth to mention that I don't have any requirements file right now, and I guess its improtant to learn how to create and add thing to it.

Comment: If you follow step 3, it will actually create the 'requirements.txt' file for you. The idea is that by creating it, when you 'git push' to heroku, heroku recognizes the 'requirements' file, and then automatically pip installs all of the dependencies onto the server.

Comment: okay, I am just not sure what the "virtual env terminal" is. is it just the windows cmd in the app directory? and then run the "pip freeze > requirements.txt" command?

Comment: The virtual env terminal is a little different, but for now yes - just run 'pip freeze > requirements.txt' in a cmd in the app directory.